# EEPC has been corrupted

Tags: boot, bios, mbr, windows-defender

Just booted my computer and got this message at boot time:
"EEPC has been corrupted"

Could not boot back into windows.
When i booted an ubuntu livecd i saw that all the files were ok.

Searched the web high and low and very little information exists.
I only found hints about this message related to a boot MBR replacement process done by Mcafee endpoint encryption tool (which encrypts your HD) that encounters an error while upgrading from some old version to a new one because of not having enough boot "low" memory for its replacement MBR code.
The solutions point you to some wintech/safetech bootable CD that requires some daily code to run that can solve it - obviously i didn't go down that path as the links to those bootable CD iso were very untrustworthy.

I don't have mcafee installed.

I tried to create a windows 10 rescue disk (start-> create rescue disk) and boot from there and fix it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After several days i managed to solve this.

I understand this boot memory thing is probably related to the type of boot bios process so i tried to **change in the bios the setting that tell BIOS how to boot**.

My old setting was on Legacy and UEFI boot process.
I assumed the new UEFI will probably have more memory for what the bootloader was trying to do so **i changed it to "UEFI only"** - it worked and everything booted fine.

After booting up windows (and creating a recovery usb drive) i went through event logs to try and see what caused this and the only clues led to windows defender (as i said before i do not have mcafee).

These are messages from the event log from the last time the computer was ok before the error:

> The start type of the Windows Defender Antivirus Boot Driver service was changed from demand start to boot start.

> The start type of the Windows Defender Antivirus Mini-Filter Driver service was changed from demand start to boot start.

> The start type of the Windows Defender Antivirus Service service was changed from demand start to auto start.

> DCOM got error "1115" attempting to start the service wuauserv with arguments "Unavailable" in order to run the server:
> {E60687F7-01A1-40AA-86AC-DB1CBF673334}

I have no idea what windows defender tried to do with the MBR and bootloader but i am happy this was solved easily.